# Problem with compiling a project containing both boost library and google tests

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, googletest

I have a project in which I'm using boost::gregorian::date. I would like to add some unit tests using gtest library. So far, I've just added the gtest library to my project but I haven't added any tests. When I'm trying to compile my project I'm getting some linker errors. I have no errors when I'm commenting in Makefile (and of course, in other files) lines related with boost. When I'm commenting in Makefile lines related to gtest I'm getting only warning:

```
warning: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.so: not a directory
```

but the program works as I want to.

When I'm trying to compile the code with both boost and gtest libraries I'm getting errors:

```
cc1plus: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.so: not a directory [-Werror]
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
lib/googletest-master/googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'lib/googletest-master/googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.o' failed
make[3]: *** [lib/googletest-master/googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:282: recipe for target 'lib/googletest-master/googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/googletest-master/googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/planner.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/planner.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:164: recipe for target 'planner' failed
make: *** [planner] Error 2
```

Here is my Makefile:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(planner)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic")

add_executable(planner [some files])

#boost
find_package(Boost)

if (NOT Boost_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find boost!")
endif ()

if (Boost_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
    message(STATUS "Boost_VERSION: ${Boost_VERSION}")
    set(BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/include")
    set(BOOST_LIBRARY_DIRS "/usr/lib")
    find_package(Boost REQUIRED date_time)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    include_directories(${Boost_LIBRARIES})
    target_link_libraries(planner ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif ()
#end boost

#gtest
add_subdirectory(lib/googletest-master)
include_directories(lib/googletest-master/googletest/include)
include_directories(lib/googletest-master/googlemock/include)
target_link_libraries(planner gtest gtest_main)
#end gtest


#cppconn
target_link_libraries(planner mysqlcppconn)
```

I'm using CLion 2019.1.4.
Can you help me solve this problem? Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Comment: Probably the culprit is here: `include_directories(${Boost_LIBRARIES})`. Since you print the content of this variable earlier, you can check if it contains any non-directories. Do you even need this line? I'd assume Boost is well-mannered library and it has all the headers in `${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen - I've commented this line and now it works. Thank you!